# SQL Server : find related columns in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find in my database where a table contains both the columns, but the code I have isn't working

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name, d.name
FROM 
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns d ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
    c.name = 'value1' AND d.name = 'value2'
ORDER BY 
    schema_name, table_name;
```

Comment: Your second inner join is `INNER JOIN sys.columns d ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID`; notice the right-hand part of the join, what are you joining on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach joins the second table (`c`) with the third one (`d`) and the inner join implies that the `object_id` should be the same  both tables. 
Your only mistake here is the incorrect join `... ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID`

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name, d.name
FROM 
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns d ON c.OBJECT_ID = d.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
    c.name = 'value1' AND d.name = 'value2'
ORDER BY 
    schema_name, table_name;
```